# Numpy/Pandas Series begins with operator? Does it exist?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a series in my dataframe (sdbfile) whose values are based on several nested conditional statements using elements from sdbfile dataframe. The series reins_code is filled with string values.

The statement below works however I need to configure to say if 'reins_code' begins' with 'R' rather than == a specific 'R#'

```
sdbfile['product'] = np.where(sdbfile.reins_code == 'R2', 'HiredPlant','Trad')
```

It doesn't like the string function startswith() as its a np.series?

Can anybody help please? Have waded through the documentation but cannot see a reference to this problem.......

Comment: Cheers. This really is a cool place. My etiquette will improve in time, as will my coding I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vectorised [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas.Series.str.startswith) to return a boolean mask:

```
In [6]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['R1asda','R2asdsa','foo']})
df

Out[6]:
         a
0   R1asda
1  R2asdsa
2      foo

In [8]:
df['a'].str.startswith('R2')

Out[8]:
0    False
1    True
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

In [9]:
df[df['a'].str.startswith('R2')]

Out[9]:
         a
1  R2asdsa
```

Comment: Thank you. In my inexperience  I was going at it from the wrong angle trying to convert before the comparison rather than select the correct str function relative to my specific pandas object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pandas `str` attribute.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

> Series and Index are equipped with a set of string processing methods
>   that make it easy to operate on each element of the array. Perhaps
>   most importantly, these methods exclude missing/NA values
>   automatically. These are accessed via the str attribute and generally
>   have names matching the equivalent (scalar) built-in string methods:

```
sdbfile['product'] = np.where(sdbfile.reins_code.str[0] == 'R', 'HiredPlant','Trad')
```

Comment: That fits the bill perfectly! Thank you!